# Как в Lotus Designer написать @-формулу для кнопки в панели действий, чтобы скрыть ее от пользователя

Tags: ibm, formula

Как в Lotus Designer написать @-формулу для кнопки в панели действий, чтобы скрыть ее от пользователя?

Прописал условие "скрытия" действия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@Contains( "0":"1":"3":"4":"5" ; AP_Status);
@Name([CN];@UserName) != "Иван Петров";
@Name([CN];@UserName) != "Анна Попова";
```

Но как я понимаю, пользователь открывший документ не может иметь UserName одновременно "Иван Петров" и "Анна Попова". Пробовал вставить оператор "OR", но Lotus Designer ругается. Формула @contains не подходит :(

Подскажите, как прописать правильно @-формулу?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Можно использовать `!@contains`. ! знак в этом случае означает отрицание оператора :)

```
!@Contains("Иван Петров":"Анна Попова"; @Name([CN];@UserName))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]